# Swift Error: 'String?' does not have member named 'dataUsingEncoding'

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdata

I am beginning at swift and I am getting an error in a program I am building:

> 'String?' does not have member named 'dataUsingEncoding'

The following is piece of my code:

```
func searchFlickrForString(searchStr:String, completion:(searchString:String!, flickrPhotos:NSMutableArray!, error:NSError!)->()){

    let searchURL:String = FlickrHelper.URLForSearchString(searchStr)
    let queue:dispatch_queue_t  = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

    dispatch_async(queue, {
        var error:NSError?

        let searchResultString = String(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: searchURL)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        if error != nil{
            completion(searchString: searchStr, flickrPhotos: nil, error: error)
        }else{


            // Parse JSON Response

            let jsonData:NSData! = searchResultString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

            let resultDict:NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) as NSDictionary

            if error != nil{
                completion(searchString: searchStr, flickrPhotos: nil, error: error)
            }
```

Can anyone please suggest a possible resolve? 
The line at which I am getting the error is:

```
 let jsonData:NSData! = searchResultString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `searchResultString` is an Optional that should be unwrapped:

```
if let jsondata = searchResultString?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
  // process jsondata here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you what's wrong:

> 'String?' does not have member named 'dataUsingEncoding'

`String?` means optional string, so the `searchResultString` variable is an optional string, and as such you have to use optional chaining in order to access to its properties and methods:

```
searchResultString?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
                  ^
```

Remember that an optional is an `enum`. When you access to a property or member of an optional variable, you are accessing to the `Optional<T>` type and not the `T` type that the optional contains. The error message is stating that `Optional<String>` doesn't have a member named `dataUsingEncoding`